# Sync between database tables and SharePoint online lists using ODBC. best approach to do so

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, csom, power-automate, console-application

We have 5 tables inside a database and we want to sync the data inside those tables to SharePoint online 5 lists. The database tables can be accessed using ODBC. So what are the approaches we have to do such a sync:-

1. Using Power Automate Flow which runs on schedule basis?
2. Write a .net console application which reads the data from the database and update SharePoint using CSOM?
3. other approach

Any advice?

Thanks

Comment: How many rows are in the tables? Will it just synchronise changes from the database to SP or SP to the database too?

Comment: @CallumCrowley there is around 6,000 rows ...the modification will still be done on the database, where SharePoint lists will just be a mirror of the databases tables.. so my main concern is how to read the data from Db using ODBC and update sharepoint..

Comment: @CallumCrowley where updating SharePoint lists using Console application &  CSOM OR using Power Automate is not an issue for me... the problem is how i can read the data using ODBC.

Comment: The issue of reading the database using ODBC is not relevant to this Stack Exchange but answers here would probably cover the SharePoint side of things e.g. using CSOM to update the tables etc.

Comment: @CallumCrowley so you mean you know the answer but do not want to write it? or you do not know the answer.. also there is a tag here for Power automate,, and my question if Power Automate support reading data using ODBc

Comment: No, I was referring to your comment about how to read the data using ODBC, which wouldn't be relevant to a SharePoint specific Stack Exchange. https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic I'm sure the community can help with the Power Automate and SharePoint side of your question however.

Comment: @CallumCrowley ok but for curiosity do you know if Power Automate supports reading data using  ODBC?

Comment: Apparently not: https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Connecting-To-Data/ODBC-Connections-Possible/td-p/493910